# UIScrollView overlaying

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I decided to use UIScrollView in my application since I have to scroll the elements appearing on the screen.

When I am checking out my scroll view in Interface Builder, it looks just perfect. But when I run my app, I am getting items from the scroll view obscuring items from the view. How can I make it work the way I need it? And why does the UIScrollView obscures items it shouldn't obscure?

Comment: could you post screenshots and code? It's not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the UIScrollView size inside of your view's subclass. If I'm understanding your problem correctly something like the code snippet below should work.

```
CGSize winSize = {500.0f, 179.0f};
yourScrollView.contentSize = winSize;
```